# Piping dependent actions in NgXS

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I have a few actions that I need to aggregate into a single action to call.

Let I have a State:

```
const store = {
  id: number;
  magic: string;
  value1: string;
}

@Action(LoadMagic)
public LoadMagic({getState, setState, dispatch}, action: {id: number}) {
  const obj = _http.get(action.id);
  setState({ id: action.id, magic: obj.magic });
}

@Action(LoadValue1)
public LoadValue1({getState, setState, dispatch}, action: {id: number, magic??}) {
  const magic = ???; //getState().magic
  const value2 = _http.get(action.id, magic);
  setState({ value2 });
}
```

So now eventually I need to create an action that will pipe these 2 actions. But as you can see LoadValue1 action needs the value that is returned from LoadMagic. So I'm looking for something like:

```
@Action(SuperAction)
public SuperAction({getState, setState, dispatch}, action: {id: number}) {
  dispatch([
    new LoadMagic(action.id),
    () => new LoadValue1(action.id, getState().magic) //you can't pass the function
  ]);
}
```

So the second action in dispatch is a sort of lazy one. But eventually, there is no such signature.

The final result is similar to:

```
@Action(SuperAction)
public SuperAction({getState, setState, dispatch}, action: {id: number}) {
  dispatch(new LoadMagic(action.id))
    .pipe(mergeMap(() => dispatch(new LoadValue1(action.id, getState().magic)));
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure that's how you would want to tackle this problem. I would recommend reading about action lifecycles: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle. It looks like you just need to use some rxjs to handle your http calls better. My advice would be figure out how to solve this without actions, then understand how actions work, then figure out if actions can help or not.

Answer (score 0):

Actions should not have return values actually. If you want to use something that was changed in the state you can do it like below:

```js
@Select(MagicState.magicSelector) magic$: Observable<any>;

dispatch(new LoadMagic(action.id))
  .pipe(withLatestFrom(magic$), mergeMap(([_, magic]) => dispatch(new LoadValue1(action.id, magic)));
```

Comment: from what I see there is no NgXS functionality to build such a pipeline with an intermediate state, so my code from the post is the best I can have

Answer (score 0):

The dependent action can be piped. And the final observable should be returned to NgXS so it will subscribe to it automatically and run the action properly.

```
@Action(SuperAction)
public SuperAction({getState, setState, dispatch}, action: {id: number}): Observable<void> {
  return dispatch(new LoadMagic(action.id))
    .pipe(switchMap(() => dispatch(new LoadValue1(action.id, getState().magic)));
}
```